# Tridion CME search not reindexing correctly

Tags: 2011, content-manager, search

We're seeing an issue on one of our client's servers where the search is not returning results for certain queries (particularly modified date queries)

I've checked the server time is OK and run the re-index tool twice and still don't see results where I expect them.

In the jetty logs I'm seeing lots of errors like this:

```
Sep 25, 2014 2:08:09 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [tridion] webapp= path=/update params={} status=500 QTime=1014 
Sep 25, 2014 2:08:09 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\solr-data\index\write.lock
```

On further investigation it seems like there's nothing in the search that was modified after a certain date and items have the wrong modified dates in search results.

I've tried deleting the .lock file from solr-data (backed up of course) and am re-running the index tool - this is currently in progress and looking at the logs, I don't see the above any more. I do see this though:

```
2014-09-25 12:28:14.865:WARN::No CallbackHandler configured: using DefaultCallbackHandler
```

Can anyone advise if this is the right approach or has seen these errors/warnings before?

Comment: Are you having 2 search indexer services running (think of outscaling scenarios)? Are you having a virus scanner holding the lock file? Does the use the process runs under have permissions on the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A re-index after deleting the `.lock` file in the `%TRIDION-HOME%/solr-data/index` directory has fixed the search for me.

It seems I can now query for items with any modified date.